# Find area id related to one city in a specific country on overpass-turbo

Tags: flutter, postman, overpass-api

I am using flutter to get some points from overpass-turbo. This is my query :

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:armenia.yerevan}}->.searchArea;
(
    node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
);out;
```

But this query in flutter and postman is not working, I don't know why!
this is that error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" lang="en" />
    <title>OSM3S Response</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</p>
    <p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 2: parse error: Unknown type &quot;{&quot; </p>
    <p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 2: parse error: An empty query is not allowed </p>
    <p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 2: parse error: ';' expected - '{' found. </p>

</body>

</html>
```

anyway in postman and flutter this query works:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area(id:3600364087)->.searchArea;
(
    node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
);out;
```

I guess, I cant use `{{geocodeArea:armenia.yerevan}}->.searchArea;`to call API, So I have to use area.

**How can I find `area(id:3600364087)` related to one city in a specific country?**

I am running

```
(
  area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="AM"];
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

but it just returns just one area id that I guess is related to the AM ->  `<area id="3600364066">`

I also tried :

```
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="AM"][admin_level=2]->.country;
area["name"="Yerevan"]->.city;
nwr(area.country)(area.city)["amenity"="pub"];
(._;>;);
out;
```

and :

```
[out:json][timeout:900];
area[name="Armenia"]['admin_level'='2']->.country;
area[name="Yerevan"](area.country)->.city;
(
 node["shop"~"mall"](area.city);
);
(._;>;);
out geom;
```

Not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `{{geocodeArea:...}}` is a special helping shortcut from Overpass-Turbo. It is not provided by overpass-api.

What seems missing in other trails, `name` tag is usually used for local name so its language differ between region. So in Armenia name tag uses Armenian.

I recommend the use specific language tag for search like `name:en` for your case. Your example now works: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Bas

```
[out:json][timeout:900];
area["name:en"="Armenia"]['admin_level'='2']->.country;
area["name:en"="Yerevan"](area.country)->.city;
(
 node["shop"~"mall"](area.city);
);
(._;>;);
out geom;
```

You can always look through OpenStreetMap to check available tags and their values. Ex: [Armenia](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/364066)